# Phpunit test a method using a service

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony

I'm trying to test a method which is using a service, and apparently it's not possible to test it like a normal method.
Does someone know what to do ?
I have this code for the moment :

```
namespace PlatformBundle\Tests;

use PlatformBundle\Controller\PaymentController;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class PaymentControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $payment;

    public function __construct() { parent::__construct(); $this->payment = new PaymentController(); }

    public function testSendEmail()
    {
        $param = array(
            'info' => array(
                'email' => 'test@test.com', 'name' => 'test', 'fare' => 'test', 'id' => 'test'
            )
        );
        $this->assertEquals(true, $this->invokeMethod($this->payment, 'sendEmail', $param));
    }

    /**
     * Call protected/private method of a class.
     *
     * @param object &$object    Instantiated object that we will run method on.
     * @param string $methodName Method name to call
     * @param array  $parameters Array of parameters to pass into method.
     *
     * @return mixed Method return.
     */
    public function invokeMethod(&$object, $methodName, array $parameters = array())
    {
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass(get_class($object));
        $method = $reflection->getMethod($methodName);
        $method->setAccessible(true);

        return $method->invokeArgs($object, $parameters);
    }
}
```

The controller where the method sendEmail is :

```
<?php

namespace PlatformBundle\Controller;

use PlatformBundle\Entity\Customer;
use PlatformBundle\Entity\Promocode;
use PlatformBundle\Entity\Transfer;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function checkoutAction(Request $req)
    {
        if (! $req->isMethod('POST')) throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();

        $info = $req->request->all();

        $this->container->get('platform.formSecurity')->testAllInformation($info);

        $this->saveCustomerIntoDb($info);

        $info['payed'] = false;
        $session = $req->getSession();
        $session->set('info', $info);

        $info['date'] = $this->container->get('platform.useful')->reverseDateFormat($info['date']);

        return $this->render('PlatformBundle:Payment:checkout.html.twig', array(
            'isIndex' => false,
            'info'    => $info,
            'stripe'  => $this->stripeConfig()
        ));
    }

    public function cancelAction(Request $req)
    {
        $req->getSession()->invalidate();
        return $this->render('PlatformBundle:Payment:cancel.html.twig', array('isIndex' => false));
    }

    public function successAction(Request $req)
    {
        $session = $req->getSession();
        $info    = $session->get('info');
        if ($info['payed']) {
            $req->getSession()->invalidate();

            if ($info === null) throw new Exception('Please contact us to make sure that the payment has been done and that your order has been taken into account.');

            $this->saveTransferIntoDb($info);

            $customer = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('PlatformBundle:Customer')->findOneBy(array(
                'email' => $info['email']
            ));

            $transfer = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('PlatformBundle:Transfer')->findOneBy(
                array('customer' => $customer->getId()),
                array('id' => 'desc'),
                1
            );

            $info['id'] = $transfer->getId();

            $info['date'] = $this->container->get('platform.useful')->reverseDateFormat($info['date']);

            $this->sendEmail($info);

            // if 5 payments done, send a promocode
            if (is_int($customer->getPayments() / 5)) {
                $this->createAndSendNewPromocode($customer);
            }

            return $this->render('PlatformBundle:Payment:success.html.twig', array(
                'isIndex' => false,
                'info'    => $info
            ));
        } else return new RedirectResponse('cancel');
    }

    private function sendEmail($info)
    {
        $mail = $this->container->get('platform.mail');
        $mail->send(
            $info['email'],
            'You have ordered a transfer for Dublin',
            $this->renderView('PlatformBundle:Mail:orderSucceed.html.twig', array('info' => $info)),
            'info@dubair.ie'
        );
        $mail->send(
            'info@airportcollections.net, info@dubair.ie, info@365onlineholidays.com',
            'A customer ordered a transfer for Dublin',
            $this->renderView('PlatformBundle:Mail:report.html.twig', array('info' => $info)),
            'info@dubair.ie'
        );
    }

    private function saveCustomerIntoDb($info)
    {
        // test if the customer already exist
        $customersList = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('PlatformBundle:Customer')
            ->findByEmail($info['email']);

        $customerExists = (sizeof($customersList) == 1 ? true : false);
        if ($customerExists) {
            $customer = $customersList[0];
        } else {
            // Create the entity
            $customer = new Customer();
            // dateRegistration, country and ip are automatically created in the constructor
            $customer->setEmail($info['email']);
            $customer->setPayments(0);
        }
        $customer->setName($info['name']);
        $customer->setPhone($info['phone']);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($customer);
        $em->flush();
    }

    private function saveTransferIntoDb($info)
    {
        $customers = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('PlatformBundle:Customer')
            ->findByEmail($info['email']);
        $customer = $customers[0];
        $customer->setPayments($customer->getPayments() + 1);

        // make promocode outdated
        if ($info['promocode'] != '') {
            $promocode = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('PlatformBundle:Promocode')
                ->findOneBy(array(
                    'value'    => $info['promocode'],
                    'outdated' => 0,
                    'type'     => 'short'
                ));
            $promocode->setOutdated(1);
        }

        // test if transfer already exist
        $transferList = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('PlatformBundle:Transfer')->findBy(
            array(
                'customer'    => $customer,
                'pickup'      => $info['pickup'],
                'destination' => $info['destination'],
                'pickupTime'  => $info['pickupTime'],
                'address'     => $info['address']
            ), // criteria
            array('pickup' => 'desc'),      // sorting
            5,                              // Limit
            0                               // Offset
        );

        // if transfer doesn't already exist, create it
        if (sizeof($transferList) == 0) {
            $transfer = new Transfer();
            $transfer->setPickup($info['pickup']);
            $transfer->setDestination($info['destination']);
            $dateArray = explode('-', $info['date']);
            $transfer->setDate(new \DateTime($dateArray[2].'-'.$dateArray[1].'-'.$dateArray[0]));
            $transfer->setAddress($info['address']);
            $transfer->setFlightTime($info['flightTime']);
            $transfer->setPickupTime($info['pickupTime']);
            $transfer->setSeats($info['seats']);
            $transfer->setAirline($info['airline']);
            $transfer->setFlight($info['flight']);
            $transfer->setType($info['type']);
            $transfer->setBags($info['bags']);
            $transfer->setFare($info['fare']);
            // join
            $transfer->setCustomer($customer);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($transfer);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }

    private function createAndSendNewPromocode($customer)
    {
        $newPromocode = $this->container->get('platform.useful')->createRandomPassword();
        $promocode = new Promocode();
        $promocode->setValue($newPromocode);
        $promocode->setType('short');
        $promocode->setDiscount(10);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($promocode);
        $em->flush();

        $mail = $this->container->get('platform.mail');
        $mail->send(
            $customer->getEmail(),
            'A promotional code for your next transfer on dubair.ie !',
            $this->renderView('PlatformBundle:Mail:promocode.html.twig', array(
                'customer'  => $customer,
                'promocode' => $newPromocode
            )),
            'info@dubair.ie'
        );
    }

    private function stripeConfig()
    {
        $stripe = array(
            "secret_key"      => "xx",
            "publishable_key" => "xx"
        );

        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);

        return $stripe;
    }

    public function stripeChargeAction(Request $req)
    {
        $this->stripeConfig();

        $info = $req->getSession()->get('info');
        $amount = ($info['fare'] * 100);

        $info['payed'] = true;
        $req->getSession()->set('info', $info);

        $token = $req->request->get('stripeToken');

        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
            'email' => $req->request->get('email'),
            'card'  => $token
        ));

        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            'customer' => $customer->id,
            'amount'   => $amount,
            'currency' => 'eur'
        ));

        return new RedirectResponse('success');
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? If the controller than you probably just need to to use it as a service and inject all the dependencies. And if it is an acceptance test then you care only about the output and not internals (Still, I would suggest using controller as service).

Comment: I'm trying to test a basic private method which uses a service to send an email. I don't really understand what you mean

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us how the controller looks like? To see what is injected there and what you are trying to test.

Comment: I ad the controller's content :) thanks for helping...

Comment: Your sendEmail function doesn't return anything, so the call to it via  `$method->invokeArgs` will just return null, and there's nothing you can test for.  Amend the sendEmail function to return true perhaps.

Comment: it doesn't change anything :/

Comment: Since I don't really have an answer which I could test I can only suggest something. 1. Use controller as a service: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html 2. Inject mailer service into the controller. 3. Test both the controller and mailer service in separate unit tests instead of acceptance tests. Because this is exactly what you are trying to do. What you are showing us is not an acceptance test but a unit test.